Could you provide tips on themes or customization for Beamer presentation frames with dense text?
I'm creating a Beamer presentation and need to include a significant amount of text on a single frame. Are there any themes that are designed to accommodate large blocks of text? Alternatively, are there any customization techniques or commands that I can use to adjust the layout and formatting of the frame to make it more suitable for dense content?

Even the manual Beamer warns that the shrink option  is "very evil", forget it!
But a \resizebox doesn't have any problems fitting any amount of text (...well, almost none). It is a good option to show the abusive clauses of a contract to the other contracting parties.

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Please read this carefully}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{minipage}{6\linewidth}
\lipsum[1-40]   
\end{minipage}}
\vfill
Do you understand now? 
\end{frame}
\end{document}


Resizebox is just as evil as shrink :P

Thank you for the feedback! I understand that the shrink option can be problematic and will avoid using it. The \resizebox method you suggested seems like a good alternative for displaying large amounts of text, and I’ll definitely keep that in mind. I appreciate your help in guiding me toward a more effective solution!
Best regards,
wuguiping

@WuGuiping Both options are equally problematic. The will tempt the user to put too much content on a slide, result in uneven font sizes throughout the presentation and will choose unsuitable glyph shapes. Don't use either of these.

@WuGuiping What my answer suggests really, albeit in a more humorous way than samcarter, is that you shouldn't do it. From my point of view too, the true problem is not to fit a large amount of text, but wanting to do that.

@WuGuiping To fit a large amount of text you only need to set a small font as \tiny and if this is not enough, try with \fontsize{2}{3}\selectfont  before of the text (experiment with the numbers to see the effect). But no matter the method, too much text will be unreadable, so what would be the point?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
Thank you for your advice! I understand your point now. Indeed, relying on shrink or resizebox can create inconsistent text sizes, which would negatively affect the readability and professionalism of the slides. I will reconsider my approach and focus more on breaking the content into smaller, more digestible pieces across multiple slides. Thanks again for the insightful feedback!
Best regards,
WuGuiping

@Fran
Thank you for your feedback and for pointing out the potential drawbacks of forcing too much content into a single slide. I agree that reducing the text size too much or using resizing methods may lead to unreadable slides. I will rethink my approach and avoid trying to fit excessive content in one slide, as you've suggested. Instead, I will focus on clearer, more concise content delivery.
Best regards,

Thank you for your assistance and suggestions.
As a high school math teacher, I occasionally need to demonstrate the complete solution process of a math problem in a beamer presentation.
Sometimes, I encounter situations where the text content exceeds the lower boundary by about 10-20%, and I have to revise the text to fit it exactly on one page. There are times when I really can't reduce the text any further, yet I want to display the entire solution process within a single frame. That's why I'm seeking your help to see if there's a better solution.

Of course, if the text characters become too small and unreadable after adjustment, I would consider displaying it across multiple slides.
Thank you all once again for your help.

@WuGuiping Then, you can use another evil option:  allowframebreaks  ;-)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Caution:
Putting a lot of text on a slide is not a good idea and your audience will probably thank you if you reconsider this plan

That being said, beamer has some tools to make more room on a frame:

use a plain frame to temporarily remove frame decorations like the head- and footline

use the shrink option to scale down the content of the frame

use the delete button of your editor to remove the overly dense frame

use a handout or similar to distribute the text instead of showing it in your presentation


Don't actually use the code below, this is just for demonstration purposes.
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Rochester}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,shrink=50]
  \lipsum
\end{frame}

\end{document}



Thanks for advice! I get too much text issue. Goal: concise, engaging slides, easy follow for audience. Valuable tips, esp. plain frames, shrinking content for space. Avoid shrinking too much, no text overload. Handouts or separate text for details, focus on key points during talk, full text later if needed. Will consider insights for final presentation. Best, Wu.
